# Integration testing Blazor apps

Tags: blazor-server-side

With Razor Pages, we had the TestServer class which we would use to write [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

How would one go about testing a [Blazor Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-server) app? When I say integration testing, I mean testing the whole app: sending a request to the TestServer which runs the app, getting an HTML page back, and checking its contents.

Is this possible with Blazor Server? If not, what is the recommended approach for integration testing Blazor Server apps?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has Selenium as an example for end-to-end testing with ASP.NET Core Blazor.

> E2E testing: A test runner runs a Blazor app containing the Component
> Under Test (CUT) and automates a browser instance. The testing tool
> inspects and interacts with the CUT through the browser. [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium)
> is an example of an E2E testing framework that can be used with Blazor
> apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/test?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Example with ASP.NET Core MVC to start from:

https://code-maze.com/automatic-ui-testing-selenium-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with IcuBlazor (https://icublazor.com/).  Full Disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: Interesting. But can it test the whole app? With routing, DI, etc? Can it run unattended?

Comment: Yes, you can test the entire app.  There is a Server-Side example on github.

Comment: An amazing work! It's a shame it's not more recognized

Comment: @Vi100 Thank you so much!!  The market share is slowly growing. Enough people rely on IcuBlazor so it is well maintained. Let me know if you have any comments/suggestions.

Comment: Aaaand less than 6 months later the repo is already gone

Comment: @DSN. The repo has gone private. The project is still very active (see https://icublazor.com/)